# Creating a list of column values by group

Tags: r, list

I have data as follows:

```
dat_in <- structure(list(Name = c("Name_a", "Name_a", "Name_a", "Name_a", 
"Name_a", "Name_b", "Name_b", "Name_b", "Name_b"), freq = c(5, 
4, 3, 2, 14, 1, 6, 0, 7), colspan = c(bb.25 = 1, bb.100 = 2, 
bb.500 = 2, bb.Infinity = 4, bb.SUM = 1, aa.25 = 1, aa.3000 = 7, 
aa.Infinity = 1, aa.SUM = 1), width = c(bb.25 = 50, bb.100 = 100, 
bb.500 = 100, bb.Infinity = 200, bb.SUM = 50, aa.25 = 50, aa.3000 = 350, 
aa.Infinity = 50, aa.SUM = 50)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L))

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  Name    freq colspan width
  <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 Name_a     5       1    50
2 Name_a     4       2   100
3 Name_a     3       2   100
4 Name_a     2       4   200
5 Name_a    14       1    50
6 Name_b     1       1    50
7 Name_b     6       7   350
8 Name_b     0       1    50
9 Name_b     7       1    50
```

I would like to create a column with list of `colspans`:

```
dat_out <- structure(list(rn = c("Name_a", "Name_b"), colspan= list(
c(1, 2, 2, 4, 1), c(1, 1, 7, 1))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image]

How do I create a list of `colspan` by name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `dplyr`, you can group data by `Name` and then summarise each group with `list`.

```r
library(dplyr)

dat_in %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(colspan = list(colspan))

# # A tibble: 2 × 2
#   Name   colspan  
#   <chr>  <list>   
# 1 Name_a <dbl [5]>
# 2 Name_b <dbl [4]>
```